# Why does the while loop from scraper never ends?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, while-loop

I have this code listed below that when it runs it is supposed to scrape data from an imdb site and go to the next page and do it again.

I am pieced this code together from bits of places from this site and it works just fine if I want just the first page (meaning remove the while true part and the nextpage line and down. as it stands, it seems to be stuck in a forever loop and I am not sure why. [IMDB Top 100 Movies](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc) is the site that I am using and there are only 2 pages so I would think this should be really quick since the one page takes about 10 seconds to run.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

I am not really familiar with while loops too much and python is new to me. I am trying to do this for an assignment to scrape 100 rows worth of data with python. I am using `BeautifulSoup`.

```
while True: 
        for container in movie_div:

            # name
            name = container.h3.a.text
            movie_name.append(name)

            # year
            year = container.h3.find('span', class_='lister-item-year').text
            movie_years.append(year)

            # runtime
            runtime = container.p.find('span', class_='runtime').text if container.p.find('span', class_='runtime').text else '-'
            movie_runtime.append(runtime)

            # IMDB rating
            imdb = float(container.strong.text)
            imdb_ratings.append(imdb)

            # metascore
            m_score = container.find('span', class_='metascore').text if container.find('span', class_='metascore') else '-'
            metascores.append(m_score)

            # There are two NV containers, grab both of them as they hold both the votes and the grosses
            nv = container.find_all('span', attrs={'name': 'nv'})

            # filter nv for votes
            vote = nv[0].text
            number_votes.append(vote)

            # filter nv for gross
            grosses = nv[1].text if len(nv) > 1 else '-'
            us_gross.append(grosses)
        
            nextpage = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com'+movie_soup.select_one('.next-page').get('href'))
  
            # create soup for next url
            nextsoup = BeautifulSoup(nextpage.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: How do you think this loop will ever end?   For one thing, you never change `movie_div`, so you're just going to process the same page over and over and over.  For another, you have no mechanism to break out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should be putting that in a for loop. You know there's two pages. Why loop forever. Here's the better code :

> the variable i is used for which page it's on. So you could make it go to page i.

```
for i in range(0, 1, 1): 
    for container in movie_div:

        # name
        name = container.h3.a.text
        movie_name.append(name)

        # year
        year = container.h3.find('span', class_='lister-item-year').text
        movie_years.append(year)

        # runtime
        runtime = container.p.find('span', class_='runtime').text if container.p.find('span', class_='runtime').text else '-'
        movie_runtime.append(runtime)

        # IMDB rating
        imdb = float(container.strong.text)
        imdb_ratings.append(imdb)

        # metascore
        m_score = container.find('span', class_='metascore').text if container.find('span', class_='metascore') else '-'
        metascores.append(m_score)

        # There are two NV containers, grab both of them as they hold both the votes and the grosses
        nv = container.find_all('span', attrs={'name': 'nv'})

        # filter nv for votes
        vote = nv[0].text
        number_votes.append(vote)

        # filter nv for gross
        grosses = nv[1].text if len(nv) > 1 else '-'
        us_gross.append(grosses)
    
        nextpage = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com'+movie_soup.select_one('.next-page').get('href'))

        # create soup for next url
        nextsoup = BeautifulSoup(nextpage.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: `range(0,1,1)` produces exactly 1 value.  But even if you changed this to `range(2)`, as you intended, this has the same issue that `movie_div` never changes, so he'll just process the same page twice.

Comment: This certainly gets through the code but shows me that the code still isn't getting me to the second page. Thank you for showing me a better way though then a while loop. I now just need to figure out how to get that second page still.

Comment: Tim Roberts, then how should one change movie_div?

Comment: I ASSUME `movie_div` should be extracted from `nextsoup`, which is where you read the new page.

Comment: So would then just repeating the line: movie_div = nextsoup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced') work?  I use this line before all of it, i guess it would make sense using it again after next soup would reset it with next soup nextsoup verion right?

Comment: Sorry, I think i need the rest of the code and try using dicts for example `movies.append({"name": "Great movie", [insert other stuff]})` or try using classes. You should try a tutorial and not StackOverFlow.

Comment: movie_div = nextsoup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced') did not work. it just gave the same 50 so i am not sure how I would change movie_div in this case either.

Comment: @Chris Still discussed the [main issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75886086/14460824)  - Even though I see the approach you are taking as a solution, it is a messy one, but if you want to take it, recap my answer from your deleted question and then try a merge before starting your loop:  `movie_div = movie_soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced')+nextsoup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced')`

Answer (score -1):

Still answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885832/getting-to-next-page-in-beautiful-soup-specific-example): The prerequisite is the understanding of the principle that the next page can always be reached through one and the same element that contains the link to this one, only if this element is no longer present, no further page follows, so `while-loop` has to `break`. It does not matter whether there are only two pages or hundreds.

Furthermore, it should be considered not to work with a lot of `lists`, as long as it is not guaranteed that they will always have the same length, so have a look at the following solution, that uses a single `list` consisting of `dicts`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc"
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

data = []

while True:
    response = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    movie_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'lister-item mode-advanced'})
    
    for e in movie_div:
        data.append({
            'movie_name':e.h3.a.text,
            'movie_year':int ( ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, e.h3.find('span', class_='lister-item-year').text) ) )
        })

    if (a := soup.select_one('a[href].next-page')):
        url = 'https://www.imdb.com'+a['href']
    else:
        break

pd.DataFrame(data)
```